# Trazer dados independente da ordem dos números se encontram

Tags: sql, oracle

Boa tarde!

Alguém pode me ajudar? Preciso trazer os dados de uma consulta (query) , com o retorno conforme abaixo, independente da ordem dos números se encontram.
Possuo uma tabela de metricias, e esta consulta é de acordo com estas metricas, e podem estar fora de ordem.
Quando executo a query, ele sempre retorna ordenando. E não quero desta forma, preciso que retorne como no pequeno exemplo ( Necessidade).
E minha consulta, trará mais de 100 colunas,e estes números podem ser aleatórios, mas que seguirão conforme meu select.
O número 100, sempre será o último.

Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT (codigo, Valor> BULK COLLECT INTO teste FROM tb_teste
(
select 1, 'Valor Produto' from dual
union all
select 2, 'Qtde Produto' from dual
union all
select 98, 'Descrição Produto' from dual
union all
select 101,'Qtde Vendas' from dual
union all
select 50, 'Qtde em Estoque' from dual
union all
select 97, 'Qtde Pedida' from dual
union all
select 100, 'Qtde a Entregar' from dual
)

Resultado:
+----+-----------------------+
| cd |     valor             |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | Valor Produto         |
| 2  | Qtde Produto          |
| 98 | Descrição Produto     |
|101 | Qtde Vendas           |
|100 | Qtde em Estoque       | 
+----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Isto virá de uma tabela ou desta montagem via 'dual' !? Eu criaria ou uma coluna de ordem (não exibida) ou um artifício tipo 1-Valor ... 2-Qtde ...

Comment: Obrigada pelo retorno. Vira de uma tabela, ,as union all existira... Como faço esta coluna de ordem ( não exibida) ou artificio tipo 1?

Answer (score 0):

1 sua tabela teria :
Cod , valor , ordem

Seria

```
Select cod , valor
From tabela
Order by ordem
```

2 uma 'gambiarra' :

```
SELECT (codigo, Valor> BULK COLLECT INTO teste FROM tb_teste
(
select 1, '1-Valor Produto' from dual
union all
select 2, '2-Qtde Produto' from dual
union all
select 98, '3-Descrição Produto' from dual
union all
select 101,'4-Qtde Vendas' from dual
union all
select 50, '5-Qtde em Estoque' from dual
union all
select 97, '6-Qtde Pedida' from dual
union all
select 100, '7-Qtde a Entregar' from dual
) order by 2
```

Comment: Nossa, gratidão pela ajuda. Vou fazer aqui e posto que deu certo. Boa noite brigadão mesmo!

Comment: Mptta, ficou perfeitoooo!  Fiz assim: